# Java extends strange output

Tags: java, extend, extends

I have written a small program in Java, a there is something I just do not understand.

Program that I have wrote has 3 classes kingClass, masterClass, and workClass. workClass extends masterClass.

Program: in the main class (kingClass) I have declared masterClass and workClass, and with the masterClass I have given values to variables x, and y. In the end of kingClass I have called a addNum function that sum two numbers from the masterClass.

Now the problem: I expected when I run the program that it will give me a sum of two numbers I have given with input, not the sum of number that I have given value in constructor.

How can write this program so that addNum returns the value of the sum of number I have enterd.

Sorry for bad english, Thank you..

kingClass

```
public class kingClass 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    masterClass mClass=new masterClass();

    mClass.setX(10);
    System.out.println(mClass.getX());

    mClass.setY(5);
    System.out.println(mClass.getY());

    workClass wClass = new workClass();
    System.out.println(wClass.addNum());
}
}
```

masterClass

```
public class masterClass 
{ 
private int x;
private int y;

masterClass()
{
    x=0;
    y=0;
}

public void setX(int a) {x=a;}
public void setY(int a) {y=a;}

public int getX() {return x;}
public int getY() {return y;}


}
```

workClass

```
public class workClass extends masterClass 
{   
int num=getX()+getY();
public int addNum() {return num;}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following two statements:

```
masterClass mClass=new masterClass();
workClass wClass = new workClass();
```

create two objects that are completely independent from one another. When you modify one, this has no effect on the other.

Did you mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    workClass wClass = new workClass();

    wClass.setX(10);
    System.out.println(wClass.getX());

    wClass.setY(5);
    System.out.println(wClass.getY());

    System.out.println(wClass.addNum());
}
```

?

The fact that `workClass` extends `masterClass` enables you to use `masterClass`'s public methods on an instance of `workClass`.

There is also a bug in your `addNum()` method:

```
public class workClass extends masterClass 
{   
    public int addNum() {return getX() + getY();}
}
```

Your current implementation adds the numbers together at construction time, disregarding any changes made to `x` and `y` post-construction.

Comment: He should fix the num attribute and addNum method too. num is set at creation time, and not reevaluated when x or y change

Comment: @TomasNarros: As it happens, I've just been adding this to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign the value to `x` and `y` when you create the object of `WorkClass`. Extending  a class just means that the data members are inherited. It doesn't mean that all the objects that you create of the base class will automatically be copied to the derived class when you create a new object of derived class.

Comment: @depecheSoul: Also, you should fix the kingClass code, as is seting x and y in a different object instance than the object where is trying to add both values.

Answer (score 0):

You've assign values to x and y on the mClass instance, not on wClass, so num will always be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors there:

- First, you are setting the values on one object (first masterClass instance), and adding values from another one (the workClass, which is a different object instance).
- Second: Your num attribute will be set at the creating time, and not reevaluated later. This is because you have defined it assigning the value.

How to fix it:

```
public class kingClass 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      //fix the first error: set and calculate at the very same object
       workClass mClass=new workClass();

       mClass.setX(10);
       System.out.println(mClass.getX());

       mClass.setY(5);
       System.out.println(mClass.getY());

       System.out.println(mClass.addNum());
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class workClass extends masterClass  {   

   public int addNum() {
      //fix the second point: don't save the value, but recalc every time you need with the actual current value of x and y
      return getX()+getY();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mClass` and `wClass` are 2 different objects.

Also the addition happens during object creation so 10 and 5 don't get added.

So you need to make modifications to `kingClass` and also `workClass`.

```
class kingClass 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    workClass wClass=new workClass();

    wClass.setX(10);
    System.out.println(wClass.getX());

    wClass.setY(5);
    System.out.println(wClass.getY());

    System.out.println(wClass.addNum());
}
}
class workClass extends masterClass 
{   
public int addNum() {return getX()+getY();}
}
```